# Assigning a previous fieldvalue to a field in the next record

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I am working on a loan amortization schedule using `Access`, I have created the following tables:

```
tblMembers - autoMemberID|txtLN|txtFN|etc
tblLoans - autoLoanID|numMemberID|etc
tblSchedules -autoScheduleID|numLoanID|numPayment#|datDue|dblBegin|...|dblEnd
tblPayments - autoPaymID|numLoanID|curAmtPaid|datPaidDate
```

and forms:

```
frmLoans - autoLoanID|etc
sbfSchedules - numPaymID|datDue|dblBegin|...|dblEnd
sbfPayments - dblAmount|datPaid
```

I have been able to generate the schedule (using `DAO recordset`) clicking a `btnRepaymentSchedule` the challenge is when I click a `btnAddPayment` still on the `sbfSchedules`, I want the value of the `dblEnd` field to be the value of the next record `dblBegin` field! I have tried using

```
dlookup(txtBeginBalance = Dlookup("EndBalance", _
    "Schedules","[ScheduleID] = Form![Schedules]![ScheduleID]-1)
```

but there is no effect but if I use

```
txtBeginBalance = txtEndBalance
```

the value of `txtEndBalance` is assigned to the value of `txtBeginBalance` of the same record (want next record).

Secondly, how can I set focus to the next record if a `contro(txtAmountPaid)` is not null on clicking the `btnAddPayment` or assigning the value of a calculation when the control is 0 or null ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for your assistance, using your recommendations, I have assigned  the dblEndBalance in the first record to be the value of dblBeginBalance in the second record; but after that, it does not continue through the recordset. Thought I did modify the SQL portion of your code to a table format) E.g: Set rs = CurrentDb.Openrecordset("Schedules", DbOpenDynaset) because if I use that, there is no effect on the clicking the btnAddPayment. Please is it possible for me to upload a picture of recordset or DB,  how can this be done. So that it will be easier to work through.@alexandre

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a recordset instead of a (much slower) dlookup?  Something like...

```
     Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
     Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select [EndBalance] from [Schedules] where [ScheduleID] = " & Form!Schedules!ScheduleID - 1)
     If Not rs.EOF Then
         Forms!Schedules!DblBegin = rs!EndBalance
     End If
     rs.Close
     Set rs = Nothing
```

...for the second q:

```
    If Not IsNull(Forms!Schedules!txtAmountPaid) then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext 
    Else
            Forms!Schedules!Your_Field_Name = calculation_goes_here
    End If
```